# MapStruct causes StackOverflowError

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, dto, mapstruct

I'm stuck with mapping entity-> DTO. My model looks like :

```
public class UserDto extends AbDto {
private String login;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String position;
private Set<RoleDto> roles;
}

public class RoleDto extends AbDto {
private String name;
private Set<PrivilegeDto> privileges;
private Set<RoleDto> users;
}

public class RoleDto extends AbDto {
private String name;
private Set<RoleDto> roles;
}
```

I use mapstruct for this, but I can't deal with the mapping. Is it a mistake at the modeling-level where trying to deal with two many-to-many relationships?

Comment: How does your mapping look like? And your entities...

Comment: The information is not enough. Post your full map struct mapping code.